# Oracle 19: Find ID of a filtered subset of rows based on the maximum value of a third column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, window-functions

Given a "summary" table with 4 or more columns:

`(ID1, ID2, SortOrder, BooleanYN1, BooleanYN2)`

For each value of `ID1`, I want the value of `ID2` that corresponds to the row with `BooleanYN{n} = Y` that has the highest value of `SortOrder`, if any such records exist.

Example:

| ID1 | ID2 | SortOrder | BooleanYN1 | BooleanYN2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | Y | N |
| 1 | 20 | 2 | N | N |
| 1 | 30 | 3 | Y | N |
| 1 | 40 | 4 | N | N |

I'm looking for `(1, 30, NULL)`, since the "most recent" (based on `SortOrder`) row for `ID1 = 1` that has `BooleanYN1 = 'Y'` is the row with `ID2 = 30`, and there are no rows where `BooleanYN2 = 'Y'`.

I built a SQL Fiddle with example data here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5bc5/6

This query doesn't work in the Fiddle because Oracle 11g doesn't support `OUTER APPLY`, but it works in Oracle 19.

```
SELECT
  p.person_id,
  mmr.appointment_id,
  flu.appointment_id,
  covid.appointment_id,
  hiv.appointment_id
FROM
  person p
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT vs.appointment_id
      FROM vaccination_summary vs
     WHERE vs.person_id = p.person_id
       AND mmr_yn = 'Y'
     ORDER BY vs.appointment_date DESC
     FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  ) mmr
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT vs.appointment_id
      FROM vaccination_summary vs
     WHERE vs.person_id = p.person_id
       AND flu_yn = 'Y'
     ORDER BY vs.appointment_date DESC
     FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  ) flu
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT vs.appointment_id
      FROM vaccination_summary vs
     WHERE vs.person_id = p.person_id
       AND covid_yn = 'Y'
     ORDER BY vs.appointment_date DESC
     FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  ) covid
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT vs.appointment_id
      FROM vaccination_summary vs
     WHERE vs.person_id = p.person_id
       AND hiv_yn = 'Y'
     ORDER BY vs.appointment_date DESC
     FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  ) hiv;
```

It seems **SUPER** inelegant and inefficient.

Surely there must be a better way to do this with window functions...or maybe un-pivoting and then re-pivoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for the `keep dense_rank` aggregate function, e.g. for your example in the sqlfiddle:

```
SELECT p.person_id,
       p.person_name,
       max(case when mmr_yn = 'Y' then appointment_id end) keep (dense_rank first order by case when mmr_yn = 'Y' then appointment_date end desc nulls last) latest_mmr_vaccine_appt_id,
       max(case when flu_yn = 'Y' then appointment_id end) keep (dense_rank first order by case when flu_yn = 'Y' then appointment_date end desc nulls last) latest_flu_vaccine_appt_id,
       max(case when covid_yn = 'Y' then appointment_id end) keep (dense_rank first order by case when covid_yn = 'Y' then appointment_date end desc nulls last) latest_covid_vaccine_appt_id,
       max(case when hiv_yn = 'Y' then appointment_id end) keep (dense_rank first order by case when hiv_yn = 'Y' then appointment_date end desc nulls last) latest_hiv_vaccine_appt_id
  FROM person p
  JOIN vaccination_summary vs
    ON vs.person_id = p.person_id
 group by p.person_id, p.person_name
 ORDER BY p.person_id;
```

See the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5bc5/18) for the results.

Comment: I wasn't, but I'm sure Paul W will see your apology :)